# Openshift v3 - update image stream to fetch changes from external docker registry

Tags: docker, openshift

I'm seeming to run into a simple problem and have the feeling I'm missing something essential.

I'm having a private docker image registry at our company, which hosts all the docker images we develop.

This registry is constantly updated during our build process and new images are pushed to it quite often.

Now we are utilizing an openshift system, with a handful of images and it's own registry.

What would be the best way to synchronize images between these 2 systems?

As example, we have an app deployed like this:

```
oc new-app myregistry.mydomain.edu/binbase/minix
```

which is running nicely.

We would now like to update this deployment with the latest changes and for this I do:

```
oc import-image minix
```

Tag Spec        Created     PullSpec                        Image
latest      23 hours ago    myregistry.mydomain.edu/binbase/minix:latest    f6646382cfa32da291e8380421ea656110090256cd195746a5be2fcf61e4edf1

which is the correct image and now executing a

```
oc deploy minix --latest
```

but this still deploys the current image, not the newly updated image.

Any idea why this, or what we are doing wrong?

All I would like todo is to now redeploy the newest image.

kind regards

Answer (score 26):

Due to utilizing the external registry on myregistry.mydomain.edu,   software updates are currently not automatically updated and pushed to the cloud system.

To update the internal images in the system, please utilize the following command

```
oc import-image <NAME OF STREAM>
```

For this to work, you will need to configure your deployment configuration with the PullPollicy '**Always**'

```
oc edit dc <NAME OF STREAM>
```

The tag you need to search for is:

imagePullPolicy: **Always**